# Can a slave say the Haggadah?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada, slave-serve-eved-avadim

Throughout the Haggadah, we make reference to the fact that originally we were slaves, but now we are freed. To quote just a couple of them:

> עבדים היינו לפרעה במצרים...ואלו לא הוציא הקב״ה את אבותינו ממצרים הרי אנו ובנינו ובני בנינו משעבדים היינו לפרעה במצרים
>
> We were slaves to Paroh in Mitzraim...Had Hashem not taken our forefathers our from Mitzraim, we, our children, and our grandchildren would be enslaved to Paroh in Mitzraim.
>
> בכל דור ודור חייב אדם לראות את עצמו כאלו הוא יצא ממצרים
>
> In every generation a person is obligated to view himself as if he left Mitzraim.
>
> הוציאנו מעבדות לחירות מיגון לשמחה ומאבל ליו״ט ומאפילה לאור גדול ומשעבוד לגאולה
>
> He took us out from slavery to freedom, from brokenness to rejoicing, from mourning to celebrating, from darkness to a great light, and from enslavement to redemption.

1. Can a slave say these portions of the Haggadah? Since we’re rejoicing over freedom, perhaps a slave would be unable to say this, as he is not free. Or perhaps since we’re rejoicing over past freedom, a slave can do so as well.
2. Is there a distinction between a Jewish slave (עבד עברי) and a quasi-Jewish slave (עבד כנעני) in this regard?
3. Is there a distinction between a Jewish slave within his first seven years and a Jewish slave past those seven years in this regard? Since in the latter case, the slave wishes to remain enslaved, rejecting Hashem’s mastery in favor of a human’s (cf. Kiddushin 22b, from Vayikra 25:55), perhaps he cannot partake in celebrating Hashem taking us as His own.

Comment: Here is a slave participating in saying the 4 questions https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.116a.12?lang=he

Comment: @ba Perhaps a slave can say the questions, but not the answers? Perhaps that’s different because others can say the Seder for him; what if he’s alone?

Comment: What's Hagaddah? One is already Yotze of telling the story by the Kiddush, so the Haggadah seems totally optional. What problem do you see in slaves reciting Psukim?

Comment: How do you explain the very existence of slavery after the Exodus?

Comment: @AlBerko 1. Since when is one yotze telling the story by Kiddush? Just by saying זכר ליציאת מצרים? The mitzvah is to go through the story - מתחיל בגנות ומסיים בשבח, and כל שלא אומר שלושה דברים אלו, etc. etc. 2. I don’t question (at least not in this particular thread) the existence of slavery, and ultimately that’s irrelevant to the question. Given that slavery exists, can a slave fulfill סיפור יציאת מצרים properly?

Comment: AFAIK That's the Shiur Deorayso. כל המוסיף הרי זה משובח - but not obligatory at all. Also you didn't specify why not? What would prevent the slaves from saying Psukim from the TOrah and Midrashim?

Comment: @AlBerko Rambam, Hil. Chametz u’Matzah 7:4 very strongly implies that מתחיל בגנות ומסיים בשבח and ארמי אבד אבי are the base obligation, and כל המרבה הרי זה משובח means anything on top of that. My problem with a slave partaking in this is that half of it is a lie for him: how can be thank Hashem for freeing him from slavery, when he’s still a slave?

Comment: I'd say the only true form of slavery is Eved Kna'ani that does not do Bris and stays a total Goy, so he's a goy anyway, the other two sorts of S. are either not a slave at all (Jewish slave) which is obligated in all the Mitzvos, or half the Jew slave that's about to be released and become free anyway. So either way I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @AlBerko Just because one isn’t קונה גופו by an עבד עברי doesn’t mean that said עבד עברי is free to do whatever he wants. All the more so an עבד כנעני where he is קונה גופו.

Comment: עבד עברי is obligated in reading the Haggadah - is it arguable? Who's arguing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91490/discussion-between-donielf-and-al-berko).